# Validate the user input

Tags: aws-lambda, slack, amazon-lex

I have a slack chat bot built using Amazon lex. Added this to a private channel. Now I want my bot to respond to messages that start with '@bot'. How can I do this validation in Lex? Now, this bot responds to all messages in the channel. I think, If we can catch a particular intent then it can be done in the lambda function. I don't know how to validate if it cannot catch an intent.

Comment: Show what you've tried in your Lambda. Are you using node.js? python?

Comment: I am using python. Found a similar issue here. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=818770  . It is unsolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon says [they are working on a catch-all solution](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=792041#792041) for messages. Until they complete this, there is a work-around. It will probably involve a bit of work.

1. Create an intent slot of type `AMAZON.StreetAddress` or similar. Let's name it `catchall`
2. Add `{catchall}` as a `Sample Utterance`.
3. Enable the `Intialization and validation code hook` and configure it to call your Lambda function.
4. Parse `event.inputTranscript` in Lambda and do whatever you want. This is where things get complicated but it does function.